# What is my option if I deleted my netplan yaml file?

Tags: server, 18.04, netplan

I have deleted the yaml config file. Now, what could I do to restore back?

the yaml file resides in

```
cat /etc/netplan/
```

Comment: Is this a server or desktop installation?

Comment: Ubuntu server 18.04

Answer (score 3):

First, using the terminal command `ifconfig`, find the relevant interface that you are trying to configure. It may be something like ens3 or enp3s0 or similar.

Now recreate the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Of course, substitute the interface you found if not enp3s0.

Spacing and indentation are crucial and must be perfect. Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Now apply the settings:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

You should be all set.