# Ethernet not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ethernet

I'm a complete novice at Linux.
I tried running Ethernet on Ubuntu 20.04 and it didn't run, I got nothing, not even wired unmanaged. Ethernet is working fine on Windows 10.
The Output of

```
lshw -c network 

  *-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
     logical name: enp5s0
     version: 15
     serial: 2c:f0:5d:66:42:09
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:45 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
```

It was disabled earlier, but after following this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049302/wired-ethernet-not-working-ubuntu-18-04), it showed wired unmanaged. I've tried various other solutions. None works for me so far.
Some solutions are specific to Ubuntu 18.04 or older.

Comment: You can try https://askubuntu.com/a/1321823/231142 but I think it needs some sort of internet to work so if you have Wifi working it should work fine.

Comment: @Terrance , I followed that solution and ended up getting network Disabled in lshw -c network, for which I used sudo ifconfig epn5s0 up, but now it doesn't even show "wired unmanaged"

Comment: oof, So it works now, the solution that worked for me is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)
The second answer (upvote wise) by vlada

Comment: What driver does it show it is using?  The reason I ask that is that the `r8169` is very unstable on the `RTL8168` chipset.

Comment: @Terrance , For now, it is r8168. So, Ig the solution is what you mentioned + the link I've shared in the previous comment. Thank you for helping me on this

Comment: That is good to know.  You can write up what you did as an answer as it was multiple things that helped you.  :)

Comment: @Terrance Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your fixes, you may find that ethernet is either intermittent, or only works after booting into Windows.

MSI/MSIX interrupts were enabled for certain ethernet cards in Ubuntu 20.xx. This can cause intermittent ethernet operation. Here's a patch to fix it. Follow the embedded instructions to install.

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779817

# filename: r8169_disable_msi

# Drop it in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top and chmod a+x it. Add 'r8169_disable_msi'
# to your kernel command line (/etc/default/grub, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
# usually.) 

# sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub # to edit the file

# Remember to update-initramfs and update-grub as necessary.

# sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
# sudo update-grub
# reboot

# For the moment it disables MSI on everything with the ID 0x10ec:0x8168, as there seems to
# be no way to get the MAC version from userspace - and certainly not before the driver is
# loaded. Other PCI IDs may need adding..

PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

disable_msi () {
    for i in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*; do 
        if [ $(cat $i/vendor) = "0x10ec" -a $(cat $i/device) = "0x8168" ]; then
            echo 0 >$i/msi_bus
        fi
    done
}

for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
        case ${x} in
        r8169_disable_msi)
        disable_msi
        break
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: I'm actually a novice at Linux, So, I don't understand even these simple instructions quite enough, I'll try to figure that out. Besides, is this solution for r8169 driver? Now, I'm using r8168

Comment: @ChiragMehta We were all Linux novices at some time :-) If your ethernet is stable and reliable, then you don't need to do this patch. If you find that ethernet doesn't work, or doesn't work after suspend/resume, or only works after booting to Windows first, then you'll need this patch. It applies to either the r8169 or r8168-dkms driver.

Comment: My ethernet is stable but for some reason I'm getting around 135 mbps download on Ubuntu, while it's around 250 mbps on windows.

Comment: @ChiragMehta Is that with VPN on? How are you testing this?

Comment: Yes, it's with VPN on, but it's from my ISP's end (my college). I tested speed on [Ookla](https://www.speedtest.net/) and [Cloudflare](https://speed.cloudflare.com/). I use Cloudflare's WARP sometimes to bypass restrictions but the speed is indistinguishable.

Comment: @ChiragMehta VPN speeds will always be lower, mostly depending on where their server is located, how busy the server is, and the fact that it's VPN. Do you run a VPN app, or use CLI, to bring VPN up/down? Are you able to test with VPN down?

Comment: VPN is on my ISP's end, not on my device. It's same for windows and Ubuntu. Since the server belongs to my Institute (IIT-Hyderabad), the ping is ~3 ms. I'm not using any VPN on my end to test speeds on both Windows and Ubuntu. 
I use CLI (cloudflare's WARP) when I need to surpass the restrictions put by my Institute, the speed tests conducted are without the use of CLI.

Comment: @ChiragMehta The only way to really test speed is without VPN. Do you have access to another network connection that doesn't use VPN, just to test?

Comment: No, the college doesn't provide any other network for any purposes, but, I don't understand why the speed would be different for Ubuntu and Windows despite having the same source and the same VPN from Institute.

Comment: @ChiragMehta It's difficult to compare Windows vs Linux... as they do the same things slightly differently. Do you connect wireless or wired? Do you have access to another network besides the college?

Comment: I'm connecting to wired network provided by college. Apart from that I've cellular data, i can use mobile hotspot.

Comment: @ChiragMehta Although I expect slow results, go ahead and speedtest cellular/hotspot.