# How to fix Nic not connecting?

Tags: networking, ethernet, nic

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 on an older PC. The NIC on the motherboard has been giving me trouble recently, occasionally disconnecting and requiring a reboot to reconnect. So I added a PCIe Ethenert Card, but it won't pull an IP address. The card is an old TP-Link NT TG-3648 hardware v2, that I found among my spare parts. I've tried both PCIe ports on my motherboard.

When I run `lspci -v | grep Ethernet -A 1` i get this output:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: TP-LINK Technologies Co., Ltd. TG-3468 Gigabit PCI Express Network Adapter
```

This tells me the system is recognizing the card, but for some reason I cannot get an IP address when I plug an ethernet cable into that port. Could this be a driver issue? There is no official linux driver for this hardware version on TP-Link's website, and I'm not sure where else I could get a driver from. When I search online, TP-Link's site is the only one that comes up that provides any driver's, but they are all  for Windows. Any help is appreciated.

```
spci -knn | grep Eth -A3 output:

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: TP-LINK Technologies Co., Ltd. TG-3468 Gigabit PCI Express Network Adapter [7470:3468]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I believe your system is loading the `r8169` driver which is very flaky on the 8168 chipset.  Possible answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1321823/231142

Comment: @Pilot6, I added the output as requested.

Comment: Do you connect to a router or directly to an ISP?

Comment: @Pilot6. I have a Net gear router R6400.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep enp`

Comment: @Terrance, it looks like the driver mentioned in your link fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem!  You are actually lucky that all you had to do was unplug the Ethernet cable and plug it back in.  Mine was getting to the point of having to do a full power cycle of the host to get it to come back up.  This was years ago that it happened to me.  After I installed the r8168 driver it has worked flawless for me.  I have never looked back since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is related to drivers. It is more likely some settings are wrong.

But you can try to install another driver by

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

Comment: I recently installed the same NIC and it works well witout `r8168`. But it is another revision of the chip. You never know.