# Internet and sound not working after switching to AMD GPU

Tags: networking, drivers, sound, iwlwifi, amdgpu

- Distro : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (No dual boot)
- Kernel :  5.19.0-41-generic
- Motherboard : MSI B365M Pro-VDH
- CPU : Intel i3-9100F
- Old GPU : NVIDIA MSI GTX 1650 LP OC
- New GPU : AMD Sapphire Radeon RX 6600
- Wifi : Intel AX200

After installing a new GPU (switch from NVIDIA to AMD)

- wifi wasn't working *(solved)*
- Ethernet wasn't always working *(solved)*
- Had no sound on HDMI *(solved)*
- White noise, whining and no sound on front on back jacks *(solved)*

---

WIFI

- Purged everything nvidia. No result with the new GPU. Reinstalled nvidia drivers but then I had problem with internet on old GPU as well.

Following chili555 advice :

- See result of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`, `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`, `iwconfig`, `rfkill list all` and `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` below.
- `sudo iwlist scan` sees the network for `wlp5s0`
- `sudo dkms status`. No result.
- **`sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` plus `reboot` solved the wifi problem**.

---

ETHERNET

- Plugged an Ethernet cable. Sometimes worked sometimes didn't (with old and new GPU). When it couldn't connect it listed as 10 Mb/s instead of 100 Mb/s in the parameters.
- In `sudo lshw -c network` in the configuration of the Ethernet interface driver was `r8169` but firmware `rtl8168h`. Followed the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321398/upgraded-to-20-04-and-lost-ethernet-connection) (from Terrance). It didn't solve the problem.
- The solution  was the most basic possible. **I changed the cable and now it worked perfectly right away.** I'm just dumb.

---

HDMI SOUND

Diagnostic :

- With the new gpu I got dummy output on hmdi and with the old gpu it worked.
- When booting I had :

```
hdaudio hdaudioC1D0: no AFG or MFG node found
snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: no codec initialized
```

- **Rolling back to kernel 5.19.0-32 following [This advice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009815) and [also this one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484563) solved the issue.**
- **Live session of 23.04 following chili555 advice worked as well so it was a kernel issue.**

---

JACKS SOUND

- I had white noise and whinning from front and back jack output with no audio. Ubuntu detected when I plugged headphones (shown when changing volume). `pulseaudio` returned :

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

- I tried to update motherboard BIOS, do a clean install of Ubuntu, everything I could find to fix `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` issues. No result.
- **chili555 suggested it was hardware issue. I tried changing motherboard and indeed it the problem disappeared.**

---

CONCLUSION

Still don't understand why changing GPU affected wifi in the first place and I probably damaged something regarding audio at some point.

Thanks chili555!

---

INFO

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl` :

```
[    3.184945] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.191765] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.191774] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    3.192250] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.319014] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    4.177073] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.264412] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: 80:38:fb:8d:14:2c
[    4.286907] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl` when ethernet doesn't work :

```
[    3.109771] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.114398] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.114411] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    3.114816] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.072973] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.099503] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x583b, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    5.099530] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x0
[    5.099542] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[    5.099554] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[    5.099565] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x0
[    5.099576] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: UMAC PC: 0xc0081da8
[    5.099587] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x4f23fe
[    5.099590] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    5.100693] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.100695] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 6
[    5.100698] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode
[    5.100701] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    5.100704] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.100706] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.100708] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004FBE16 | branchlink2
[    5.100710] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004F23FE | interruptlink1
[    5.100712] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004F23FE | interruptlink2
[    5.100714] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004FAAD0 | data1
[    5.100716] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[    5.100718] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[    5.100721] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    5.100723] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x000F0BB3 | tsf low
[    5.100725] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    5.100727] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    5.100729] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x000F65AD | time gp2
[    5.100731] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    5.100734] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    5.100736] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    5.100738] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[    5.100740] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
[    5.100743] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x8003FC12 | hcmd
[    5.100745] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    5.100747] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    5.100749] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    5.100751] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    5.100753] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    5.100755] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    5.100757] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004FAAD0 | wait_event
[    5.100759] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    5.100761] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    5.100763] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.100765] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.100768] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.100770] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    5.100772] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000F820 | flow_handler
[    5.100813] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.100815] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[    5.100818] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    5.100821] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.100823] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80455E3C | umac branchlink2
[    5.100825] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80472146 | umac interruptlink1
[    5.100828] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xC008155C | umac interruptlink2
[    5.100830] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    5.100832] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xC008155C | umac data2
[    5.100834] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    5.100837] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    5.100839] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    5.100841] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x000F65AA | frame pointer
[    5.100843] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xC0887F0C | stack pointer
[    5.100846] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    5.100848] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    5.100859] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[    5.100861] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    5.100873] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000583B | IML/ROM data1
[    5.100884] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    5.100892] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    5.100896] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x60000041 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    5.100900] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    5.100905] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    5.100910] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    5.100914] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    5.100919] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    5.100923] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    5.100928] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    5.100932] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.100939] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.100946] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    5.100953] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    5.100957] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    5.100960] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    6.395198] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    6.413244] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: retry init count 0
[    6.416688] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.547744] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.613996] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: 80:38:fb:8d:14:2c
[    6.893704] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`sudo dmesg | grep wlp` :

```
[    4.286907] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`iwconfig` :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

`rfkill list all` :

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` :

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `iwconfig` and: `rfkill list all` If you run: `sudo iwlist scan` does it see your network? No need to post the entire result, just tell us if your network is shown. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Please see post #6 here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252913 If you do: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` does the wireless start working? Is therer any change from a cold boot versus a reboot?

Comment: In regard to the link I gave, I wanted to see if removing and reloading the driver module would help. It did not. Although your wireless is working now, I suspect it will fail again and need a few reboots. What does this tell us? `sudo dkms status` and: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` Finally, let's fix it permanently before we think about a beer!

Comment: Have you tried a live session of Ubuntu 23.04 using the 6.2.0-xx kernel version?

Comment: "Headphone detected when I plug them (as before) but still no audio." How are they recognized? Are there any BIOS/EFI settings related to audio jacks?

Comment: When I change the volume it's written "headphone" on the meter. There is a setting related to audio in BIOS ```HD Audio Controller``` and when I disable it I get no sound at all. Trimmed text in my question and added info about pulseaudio and Ethernet driver.

Comment: "White noise, whining and no sound" I now suspect this is a hardware defect. I recommend that you consult the motherboard manufacturer. I am very glad that the wifi is now working properly.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your help on the wifi. So can I offer a beer in any way? I'm still going to investigate pulseaudio because I'm not the first one to get the ```Daemon already running``` and ```pa_pid_file_create() failed``` issue

Comment: Nothing is necessary. I do this because it's fun. If, however, you must: https://ubuntu.com/community/contribute/donation

Comment: Will do! Thanks again, I learned a lot in the process

Answer (score 1):

Mostly thanks to chili555 :

- `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` plus `reboot` solved the wifi problem.
- Ethernet issue was a basic cable issue.
- HDMI sound issue was a kernel issue. Solved by rolling back to kernel 5.19.0-32 or updating to Ubuntu 23.04
- Sound on jacks was a motherboard issue. Had to change it.