# Asus AX3000 not working in PCIe x16 slot on Gygabite B550M DS3H

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi, pcie

After [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468666/internet-and-sound-not-working-after-switching-to-amd-gpu) I had to change my motherboard because sound wasn't working. Now with the new one I can't get the WiFi and Bluetooth to work so I'm asking for help again.

- Distro : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (No dual boot)
- Kernel :  5.19.0-43-generic
- Motherboard : Gigabyte B550M DS3H PULSE
- CPU : AMD Ryzen 5 5600
- GPU : AMD Sapphire Radeon RX 6600
- WiFi and Bluetooth : ASUS AX3000 (Intel AX200NGW chip)

The WiFi card is set in a PCIe x16 slot because the GPU blocks the only PCIe x1 slot.
I could return the motherboard and order one with WiFi built in but I'd prefer to make if work with what I have.

Here's some info :

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    6.003373] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.028152] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    6.028165] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    6.029328] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.293592] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.420774] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.485614] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 80:38:fb:8d:14:2c
[    6.500580] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Networks appear when `nmcli device wifi list` and same goes for bluetooth devices, which are visible in the parameters.

Comment: Everything looks perfect so far. What about the wifi is not working? When you click the Network Manager icon at the top right, do you see networks? Do networks appear here? `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for coming back. Yes networks appear. Bluetooth devices as well. The problem is can't connect to them. In the parameters the little wheel keeps spinning and nothing happens when I try to connect to them.

Comment: Can you connect after `sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off && sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 txpower 15`

Comment: No, I can't connect

Comment: Okay I found the solution. Wifi card is Pcie 2.0. Setting it accordingly in BIOS solved the issue. Thank to you both for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

The Pci-e port is 3.0 and the wifi card is 2.0. Setting it accordingly in BIOS solved the issue.